# Global Inverse Function Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ is $\mathcal C^1$. For each of the following assertions, give a brief proof or a counterexample.

(a) If $f$ is one-to-one, then $Df(x)$ is invertible for all $x$.
(b) If $Df(x)$ is invertible for all $x$, then $f$ is an open mapping, i.e. the image of every open set is open.
(c) If $Df(x)$ is invertible for all $x$, then $f$ is onto.
(d) If $Df(x)$ is invertible for all $x$, the $f$ is one-to-one.
(e) If $f$ is one-to-one and onto, and $Df(x)$ is invertible for all $x$, then $f^{-1}$ is $\mathcal C^1.$

This question really made me doubt my understanding of IFT. If someone could correct/verify my answers that would be greatly appreciated. I may have gotten them all wrong:

a) True (I think?). If $f^{-1}$ is also differentiable then its derivative is $[Df]^{-1}$. I don't know if the inverse is necessarily $C^1$.

b) False. IFT gaurantees a $\textit{local}$ inverse. I don't think we can connect these local inverses to produce $f^{-1}$ defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

c) True. Again, I'm not sure about this extension to a global statement, but this seems to be true. If I have a local inverse at all points, then I must be hitting anything in the target.

I'm guessing F, T for the last two but I'm really not sure. Thank you!

Comment: Please use an image-to-LaTeX converter to convert your question into LaTeX so that people with screen readers can read them. Also LaTeX is more searchable than images.

Comment: $x \mapsto x^3$ is bijective.

Comment: You are guessing. I luv it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4577592/27978

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3112603/27978

Comment: Try to prove each statement. If you get stuck, try to identify carefully the exact step where you get stuck. Try to use that to find a counterexample. If you stuck, try to figure out where you get stuck. Try to use that to try again to prove the statement. Repeat. If after an hour or so of trying this, go do something else and try again the next day.

Answer (score 1):

a) This is false. The counterexample is $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = x^3$. This is a one-to-one function but at $x = 0$ it's derivative is equal $0$, i.e. $Df(0)$ is not invertible.

b) This is true. In IFT, the derivative is invertible at just one point, but here we're assuming that it's invertible at all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $O\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is an open set and $a\in O$. Because of the IFT, there exists open sets $a\in U\subset O$ and $f(a)\in V\subset f(O)$ such that $f$ is an diffeomorphism betwen $U$ and $V$. Hence, $f(O)$ is an neighborhood of $f(a)$ and, because $a$ is an arbitrary point of $O$, $f(O)$ is an neighborhood of all of it's point and, therefore, an open set.

c) It's false. The counterexample is the function $\tan^{-1}\colon\mathbb{R}\to\Big(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)$, whose image is limited.

e) To prove that $f^{-1}$ is $C^1$, one just need to prove that $Df^{-1}$ is an continuous function. Because $f$ is onto, to every $y$ there exists $x$ such that $y = f(x)$. By the ITF, there exists neighborhoods $x\in U$ and $y\in V$ such that $f$ is and $C^1$-diffeomorphism betwen them. This implies that $f^{-1}$ is also an $C^1$-diffeomorphism and then $Df^{-1}$ is continuous at $y$. Hence, of every $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, the derivate $Df^{-1}$ is continuous at $y$ and, therefore, $f^{-1}$ is $C^1$.

Unfortunately I couldn't solve d).